# ExtJS panel does not load grid content inside

Tags: extjs, extjs6

I'm not sure why, but ExtJS does not display content of grid if it is in regular Panel.

When I add grid to tab.Panel then all is fine.

Fiddle (with multiple files):
https://fiddle.sencha.com/?fiddle=19bi#fiddle/19bi

Check that Home Tab has grid. It does not use Ext.Panel. Users tab uses and no grids are displaying.

*Files in my project:*

Simple store (app\store\Personnel.js)

My Panel with 1 item. **When I change Ext.tab.Panel to Ext.Panel then grid content does not show** (modern\src\view\main\Main.js)

```
Ext.define('MyApp.view.main.Main', {
    extend: 'Ext.tab.Panel',
    xtype: 'app-main',

    ...

    items: [
    {
        title: 'Home',
        iconCls: 'x-fa fa-home',
        layout: 'fit',
        // The following grid shares a store with the classic version's grid as well!
        items: [{
            xtype: 'mainlist'
        }]
    }
]
});
```

Item itself (myapp\modern\src\view\main\List.js):

```
Ext.define('MyApp.view.main.List', {
    extend: 'Ext.grid.Grid',
    xtype: 'mainlist',

    requires: [
        'MyApp.store.Personnel'
    ],

    title: 'Personnel',

    store: {
        type: 'personnel'
    },

    ...
});
```

Comment: Not sure about the validity of Ext.Panel class name. Did you try Ext.panel.Panel?

Comment: https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.0/6.0.2-modern/#!/api/Ext.Panel . This is a modern theme.

Comment: Please make a fiddle.

Comment: https://fiddle.sencha.com/?fiddle=19bi#fiddle/19bi. Check that Home Tab has grid. It does not use Ext.Panel. Users tab uses and no grids are displaying. Fiddle has multiple files

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is with the layout.

This shows the contents:

```
/**
 * This view is an example list of people.
 */
Ext.define('MyApp.view.main.Users', {
    extend: 'Ext.Panel',
    layout:'vbox',
    xtype: 'users',

    items: [{
        xtype: 'usersgrid',
        flex:1
    },{
        xtype: 'usersgrid',
        flex:1
    }]
});
```

As far as I know, a grid cannot force the view to take the height of all rows. Instead, the view is either too big or too small. In the first case, there is white space below the rows, in the second case, the grid is scrollable.

Comment: Brilliant answer! Thanks! I couldn't even imagine that content is on page, but hidden for some reason. It is hard to analyze page HTML that ExtJS generates.

Comment: When analyzing, use `Ext.ComponentQuery.query()`; I have used the following on the grid:     `listeners:{
        painted:function() {
            console.log(Ext.ComponentQuery.query("usersgrid")[0].getItems());
        }
    }`. In chrome I could then easily analyze that there are 25 "items" (cells) in the grid.